# how to add a group to module maintenance odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I want to add groups to module maintenance in odoo 10, for more security

is it possible to add groups like : maintenance/manager, maintenance/user like other modules mrp stock ...

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes create a category of maintenance and add user and manager group in it